# AndroidStudio doesn't change the application

Tags: android

I have problem. Yesterday everything was working fine, but today, no matter what I write in files, when I run application on my phone it's always the same application from yesterday. What's wrong?

Comment: Just clean & rebuild project project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clean your project.
2. Invalidate Caches (Android Studio > File > Invalidate caches and Restart)
3. Uninstall your app from emulators and devices.
4. Run your app